# How to disable html drawer layout in website using selenium in Java?

Tags: java, html, selenium, automation

I am doing an automation for a website and I have this drawer Menu Panel that I want to open verify some elements in it then close it or hide it.

I am stuck now while trying to close/hide this drawer.

However, in the HTML I found this when it opens:

- "is-visible" added to class name
- Tag aria-hidden="false  And when its closed/hidded"
- "is-visible" removed from title
- Tag aria-hidden = true

Here is the code for login and then open Menu and check Logout is displayed

```
login.SuccessfulLogin(testdata);
            login.clickLink(By.xpath(testdata.getParam("MenuLocator")));
            login.WaitForElementVisibilty(By.xpath(testdata.getParam("loginLocator")));
            login.compareValue(testcase, "", expectedResultMap.get("MenuLoginTxt"),
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(testData.getParam("loginLocator"))).getText());     
            // here should enter the code to close the menu!        
            log.info("User Logged in Successfully");
```

See screenshot
(Menu opened on the Left-side & HTML code highlighted on Right-side)

[image]

Comment: Please provide the relative code so we can see your problem in action.

Answer (score 0):

Website you are checking is accessible from network so i checked how it works. You just need to click outside of menu area. Correct element is `div.mdl-layout__obfuscator`.

Using java you can do this like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mdl-layout__obfuscator")).click();
```

Note: there is only one element with this class name on this page so this is sufficient. You can use any other selector type, not necessarily css selector.